# Joining/matching data frames in R

Tags: r, join, left-join, fuzzy-comparison

I have two data frames.

The first one has two columns: `x` is water depth, `y` is temperature at each depth.

The second one has two columns too, `x` is also water depth, but at different depth compared to that in the first table. The second column `z` is salinity.

I want to join the two tables by `x`, by adding `z` to the first table. I have learned how to join tables using 'key' in `tidyr` , but that only works if the keys are identical. The `x` in these two tables are not the same.

What I want to do is to match the depth `x` in table 2 to that within 10% of that in table 1 (i.e. match 1.1 in table 2 `x` to 1.0 in table 1 `x`).

How can I do this?

```
Table 1
| x | y  |
|---|----|
| 1 | 25 |
| 2 | 26 |
| 3 | 27 |

Table 2
| x    | z  |
|------|----|
| 1.1  | 30 |
| 2.05 | 35 |
| 3.8  | 34 |
```

I want

```
Table 1
| x | y  | z  |
|---|----|----|
| 1 | 25 | 30 |
| 2 | 26 | 35 |
| 3 | 27 | NA |
```

The first two 'x' values have matches (within 10% absolute difference) in `Table 2`. The third one doesn't.

Comment: Have you seen the `fuzzyjoin` package?

Comment: Just checked. Seems to be the right thing. Thanks! So many packages to follow!

Comment: @JianghuiDu I dont think `fuzzyjoin` is going to help you much in this case. Better would be to provide a reproducible example so that appropriate solution can be provided.

Comment: I have added the example.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit after data was provided:*

Taking data definition from @MKR's post:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_left_join(Table_1, Table_2,match_fun = function(x,y)  y> x & y<=1.1*x )
# Joining by: "x"
#   x.x  y  x.y  z
# 1   1 25 1.10 30
# 2   2 26 2.05 35
# 3   3 27   NA NA
```

---

*general explanations with fake data (first answer)*

**fake data**

```
iris1 <- head(iris[1:2])
iris1
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
# 1          5.1         3.5
# 2          4.9         3.0
# 3          4.7         3.2
# 4          4.6         3.1
# 5          5.0         3.6
# 6          5.4         3.9

iris2 <- head(iris[c(1,3)])
set.seed(1)

# add noise
iris2$Sepal.Length <- iris2$Sepal.Length + rnorm(6,sd=0.05)

# shuffle rows
iris2 <- iris2[sample(seq(nrow(iris2))),]

iris2
#   Sepal.Length Petal.Length
# 5     5.016475          1.4
# 2     4.909182          1.4
# 4     4.679764          1.5
# 6     5.358977          1.7
# 3     4.658219          1.3
# 1     5.068677          1.4
```

**code**

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
fuzzy_left_join(iris1,iris2,match_fun= function(x,y) y>0.99*x & y<1.01*x )
# Joining by: "Sepal.Length"
# Sepal.Length.x Sepal.Width Sepal.Length.y Petal.Length
# 1            5.1         3.5       5.068677          1.4
# 2            4.9         3.0       4.909182          1.4
# 3            4.7         3.2       4.679764          1.5
# 4            4.7         3.2       4.658219          1.3
# 5            4.6         3.1             NA           NA
# 6            5.0         3.6       5.016475          1.4
# 7            5.4         3.9       5.358977          1.7
```

We see that some rows matched really well, let's take a look at the exceptions. The row number 4 had too much noise added in `iris2`, so it got paired with row 3, which has 2 matches. As I chose a left join, row 4 is still shown, but with `NAs` for `iris2`'s columns.

As I understand it:

- The joining columns will be expanded
- The function takes these long columns (`6*6==36` elements here) as arguments
- We an apply vectorized functions (such as `<` or `&` in this case) to return a vector of logical that will filter these long columns in order to build the output `data.frame`.

`distance_left_join` is more straightforward to use, but then it's absolute distance, not relative.

Comment: Great! That does work! Another related question. What if I have multiple keys, for example key1, key2, key3. I want to match key1 and key2 exactly, but only match key3 under certain constraint ?

Comment: 1st please note that i edited my answer, thought the output doesn't change, i was using `multi_match_fun` wrong

Comment: `match_fun` can be a list of function, you should mention the `by` argument explicitely to be safe, and then you can provide a list of functions that will apply on each pair

Comment: if you provide only one it will be used on all pairs

Answer (score 0):

An option using `sqldf` can be achieved as:

```
library(sqldf)


sqldf("select T1.x, T1.y, A.z from Table_1 T1
left join (select Table_1.x, Table_1.y, Table_2.z from Table_1 
   left join Table_2 where round((100*abs(Table_1.x - Table_2.x)/Table_1.x),0) <= 10) A 
on T1.x = A.x")

#   x  y  z
# 1 1 25 30
# 2 2 26 35
# 3 3 27 NA
```

**Data:**

```
Table_1 <- read.table(text = 
"x  y  
1   25  
2   26  
3   27",
header = TRUE)


Table_2 <- read.table(text = 
"x  z  
1.1    30  
2.05   35  
3.8    34",
header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain the logic behind it, it's not so clear, especially as OP had some rules in mind

Comment: I think you mistake my intention. I'm joining `Table 2` to `Table 1` based on the relative distance of `x`, not just matching them by order. Or maybe I'm confused, how and where did you put in the matching criteria?

Comment: I agree. I have made a mistake in understanding question. I'm correcting it.

Comment: Thanks! Great to try them all.