# for each row in a data frame, find whether there is a "close" row in another data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, summarization

I have the following data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
df <- data_frame(x = sample(seq(0, 1, 0.1), 5, replace = T), y = sample(seq(0, 1, 0.1), 5, replace = T), z= sample(seq(0, 1, 0.1), 5, replace = T) )
```

For each row in `df`, I would like to find out whether there is a row in `df2` which is close to it ("neighbor") in all columns, where "close" means that it is not different by more than 0.1 in each column.

So for instance, a proper neighbor to the row `(1, 0.5, 0.5)` would be `(0.9, 0.6, 0.4)`.
The second data set is

```
set.seed(42)
df2 <- data_frame(x = sample(seq(0, 1, 0.1), 10, replace = T), y = sample(seq(0, 1, 0.1), 10, replace = T), z= sample(seq(0, 1, 0.1), 10, replace = T) )
```

In this case there  is no "neighbor", so Im supposed to get "FALSE" for all rows of `df`.

My actual data frames are much bigger than this (dozens of columns and hundreds of thousands of rows, so the naming has to be very general rather than "x", "y" and "z".

I have a sense that this can be done using `mutate` and `funs`, for example I tried this line:

```
df <- df %>% mutate_all(funs(close = (. <= df2(, .)+0.1) & (. >= df2(, .)-0.1))
```

But got an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does your expected output look like

Comment: the expected output is identical to `df`, with an addition TRUE or FALSE column to indicate whether a neighbor was found in `df2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use package `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

# adding two rows that match
df2 <- rbind(df2,df[1:2,] +0.01)

df %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(df2,match_fun= function(x,y) y<x+0.1 & y> x-0.1 ) %>%
  mutate(found=!is.na(x.y)) %>%
  select(-4:-6)

# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#     x.x   y.x   z.x found
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
# 1   1     0.5   0.5 TRUE 
# 2   1     0.8   0.7 TRUE 
# 3   0.3   0.1   1   FALSE
# 4   0.9   0.7   0.2 FALSE
# 5   0.7   0.7   0.5 FALSE
```

find more info there: [Joining/matching data frames in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50708000/joining-matching-data-frames-in-r/50708533#50708533)

Answer (score 0):

The machine learning approach to finding a *close* entry in a multi-dimensional dataset is Euclidian distance.

The general approach is to normalize all the attributes.  Make the range for each column the same, zero to one or negative one to one. That equalizes the effect of the columns with large and small values.  When more advanced approaches are used one would center the adjusted column values on zero. The test criteria is scaled the same.

The next step is to calculate the distance of each observation from its neighbors. If the data set is small or computing time is cheap, calculate the distance from every observation to every other. The Euclidian distance from observation1 (row1) to observation2 (row2) is sqrt((X1 - X2)^2 + sqrt((Y1 - Y2)^2 + ...).  Choose your criteria and select.

In your case, the section criterion is simpler. Two observations are close if no attribute is more than 0.1 from the other observation. I assume that df and df2 have the same number of columns in the same order. I make the assumption that close observations are relatively rare. My approach tells me once we discover a pair is distant, discontinue investigation. If you have hundred of thousands of rows, you will likely exhaust memory if you try to calculate all the combinations at the same time.

~~~~~

You have a big problem.  If your data sets df and df2 are one hundred thousand rows each, and four dozen columns, the machine needs to do 4.8e+11 comparisons.  The scorecard at the end will have 1e+10 results (close or distant).  I started with some subsetting to do comparisons with tearful results. R wanted matrices of the same size. The kluge I devised was unsuccessful. Therefore I regressed to the days of FORTRAN and did it with loops.  With the loop approach, you could subset the problem and finish without smoking your machine.

From the sample data, I did the comparisons by hand, all 150 of them: nrow(df) * nrow(df2) * ncol(df). There were no close observations in the sample data by the definition you gave.

Here is how I intended to present the results before transferring the results to a new column in df.

```
    dfclose <- matrix(TRUE, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = nrow(df2))
    dfclose # Have a look
```

This matrix describes the distance from observation in df (rows in dfclose) to observation in df2 (colums in dfclose).  If close, the entry is TRUE.

Here is the repository of the result of the distance measures:

```
    dfdist <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = nrow(df2))
    dfdist # have a look; it's the same format, but with numbers
```

We start with the assumption that all observations in df aare close to df2.
The total distance is zero.  To that we add the Manhattan Distance. When the total Manhattan distance is greater than .1, they are no longer close. We needn't evaluate any more.

```
    closeCriterion <- function(origin, dest) {
      manhattanDistance <- abs(origin-dest)
      #print(paste("manhattanDistance =", manhattanDistance))
      if (manhattanDistance < .1) ret <- 0 else ret <- 1
    }

    convertScore <- function(x) if (x>0) FALSE else TRUE

    for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
      print(paste("col =",j))
      for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
        print(paste("df row =",i))
        for (k in 1:nrow(df2)) {
          # print(paste("df2 row (and dflist column) =", k))
          distantScore <- closeCriterion(df[i,j], df2[k,j])
          #print(paste("df and dfdist row =", i, "  df2 row (and dflist column) =", k, "     distantScore = ", distantScore))
         dfdist[i,k] <- dfdist[i,k] + distantScore
         }
      }
    }

    dfdist  # have a look at the numerical results

    dfclose <- matrix(lapply(dfdist, convertScore), ncol = nrow(df2))
```

I wanted to see what the process would look like at scale.

```
    set.seed(42)
    df <- matrix(rnorm(3000), ncol = 30)
    set.seed(42)
    df2 <-matrix(rnorm(5580), ncol = 30)
    dfdist <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(df), ncol = nrow(df2))
```

Then I ran the code block to see what would happen.

~ ~ ~

You might consider the problem definition.  I ran the model several times, changing the criterion for closeness.  If the entry in each of three dozen columns in df2 has a 90% chance of matching its correspondent in df, the row only has a 2.2% chance of matching. The example data is not such a good test case for the algorithm.

Best of luck

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way to calculate that column without `fuzzyjoin`

```
library(tidyverse)

found <- 
  expand.grid(row.df  = seq(nrow(df)),
              row.df2 = seq(nrow(df2))) %>% 
      mutate(in.range = pmap_lgl(., ~ all(abs(df[.x,] - df2[.y,]) <= 0.1))) %>% 
      group_by(row.df) %>% 
      summarise_at('in.range', any) %>% 
      select(in.range)
```